# Ubuntu taking a long time (if it doesn't fail) from http://releases.ubuntu.com/, but downloads fast and fine from a provided mirror

Tags: firefox, downloads, curl, download-speed

So here is what is going on:

I am trying to download Ubuntu in a shell script, and used their releases page (`releases.ubuntu.com`) as it was the first Ubuntu download url I found. Well, it was slow and eventually failed halfway through (using `curl`), and I thought "huh, that is funny." So I tried again using my browser (Waterfox 43.0.4, Mac), and this time it got even less progress before it failed, and was still slow. So I went to the [downloads page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?country=US&version=14.04.3&architecture=amd64), and it download 4 times as fast and didn't fail. I also noticed that it used a mirror as well (`mirror.mit.edu`). I tested both websites a few more times, and got the same results, with the mirror downloading fast and completely, and Ubuntu's releases page downloading slowly and failing. So, what is up with `releases.ubuntu.com`, or what can I fix on my end to make it download properly?

Comment: Likely nothing is wrong on both ways, and also nothing to fix. Too many people hit releases.ubuntu.com, which is expected, and which is why there are mirrors and torrent links.

Comment: @mikewhatever: I believe your comments holds the answer to this question. "What you're experiencing is not ideal but the intended behaviour given technical resource constraints."

Comment: @mikewhatever As DavidFoerster mentions, if you make that an answer, I'll accept.

Comment: @FlareCat Welcome to the Internet! Speed is relative, especially when downloading large files. There's any number of problems the server can have, not to mention the multitude of problems that can happen to the data between you and the server. That's why mirrors are so great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing seems to be wrong on both ends, and nothing needs fixing. Downloads from a local mirror will usually be much faster, which is why there are multiple mirrors, as well as bittorrent links.